# PageViews, Dynamic Page visits counter similar to Google Analytics or Alexa?

Tags: php, mysql, tracking, pageviews

I want to put a hit counter or visits to display for my website http://www.deerpages.co on every dynamic pages. I'm using Php and MySQL. But, I'm thinking of once I've put every tracking in per row inserted, then that table will be full soon.

Is there any external ways we can do this? I mean, like Google Analytics or Alexa type of trackings? and can be able to display them?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put a page counter on content, you change the value of the counter in your database, not insert a new row for it each time.

Assuming your table looks something like this:

```
contentTable
+------+---------+
| ID   | Counter |
|------|---------|
| 1    | 35      |
| 2    | 54      |
+------+---------+
```

You can update the row with ID of 1 like this:

`update contentTable set Counter=Counter+1 where ID=1;`

Assuming that you link each page to an ID in the database. You can also easily keep all your content in the same database table.

Edit:
If you want to store other data about each visitor, then make a separate hitCounter table along the following lines:

```
    CounterTable
+----+---------+----------+---------|
| ID | Counter | HTTP_REf | Country |
|----+---------+----------+---------|
| 1  | 46      | SomeData | USA     |
| 2  | 28      | Data2    | Aus     |
+----+---------+----------+---------+
```

And update the data as required based on the users individual data columnsm such as:
`insert into counterTable (ID, Counter, HTTP_Ref, Country)
    values (null, 1, '".$HTTP_REF."', '".$country."')
    On Duplicate Key update set counter=counter+1;`

(Assuming Keys of ID, HTTP_Ref and Country)

Having said that, I would suggest either looking at using some space on the database (really, you will need a *LOT* of hits to "fill up the tables" as such) or maybe simply split the basic counter with a stats table that lists Country, Referrer and the like into different tables.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this style is okay and nothing problem I can handle it. But, I mean for tracking also the country and some details like HTTP_REFERER which I might store.  I've done this before but you know, it will populate tables soon.

Comment: Maybe, I'll try your suggestion and implement this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: So, meaning it inserts every new row in the database every visit? or just update the existing row if match the same id?

Comment: anyways, I'll follow your suggestion.

Comment: In MySQL there is a [lovely syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) that allows you to make an insert statement, but it it violates the key(s) on the table, it performs a different action, and updates the row you gave. In the example SQL I wrote above, it would insert a new row, unless ID, HTTP_Ref and Country where already there (assuming they are the keys) and in that case merely update the Counter to +1.

Comment: Sounds great!, I will really implement your suggestions and solve my problem in minimizing space in the database. Glad that you're there to help me out. God bless you more!

Comment: The other thing you might want to think about is having a `counter` table to keep track of your views on each page, but a different table to keep track of your `Referrers`. You could increment the counter on the referrer table with each visit while at the same time incrementing the counter table. If you re worried about space, this will minimize the data rows as they won't be split by referrer->PageID.